# How to make my SQL Query ORDERED by names that start with a keyword?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sql query that I want to make it be ordered by the name that starts with a specified keyword.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%tel%'
```

--

```
ID   Name
1    Protel
2    Tastela
3    Telephones
4    Telling
5    Protelix
6    Zetel
```

I have the query "tel", I want to find all those results up there, and it is doing correctly. But the order of these rows are not how I want them, I want them to have the most relevant (what I consider to be, the ones that start with the keyword "tel" ) results in the first rows  so the result I want should be something like:

```
ID   Name

3    Telephones
4    Telling
2    Tastela
1    Protel
5    Protelix
6    Zetel
```

how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
order by name like 'tel%' desc, name
```

This works because the expression `name like 'tel%'` returns a boolean.  A true value is treated as `1` and a false as `0`.  You want the true values first, hence the `desc` on the `order by`.

Comment: If possible, can you example on how we can achieve this using `field(...)` function?

Comment: @Ravinder . . . In this case, you can't.  If you have a question about your data, then ask a question.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, You are absolutely right. I didn't know we could do that LIKE term in the "order by". :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: No. I don't have any data. I was just trying a solution with a `field` function.